# React Native Invariant Violation error, but nothing seems to be broken

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to develop an application with React Native, every now and then, I get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

with no further explanation.

Today the application worked fine, I accidentally had a letter written outside of a functional component, I had an error of course, deleted the extra letter and then I got this error.
Nothing seems to fix this error this time.

I tried closing the server, clearing cache, running the application again, deleted node_modules and did npm install again, nothing works. I have no idea what could go wrong, the application worked fine, and after that letter the application just won't run.

Any ideas? What causes this error?

Comment: hey John, recently I updated an app from RN 61 to 63 and faced this issue. From my research and experience, probably there is an external library causing this, at least for me that was the case. Try commenting the imports for each of the libraries you're using, one at a time and executing your app again. Check this answer in this issue on github, where they discuss this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26687#issuecomment-544218858

Comment: @MarcVictor Thank you very much Marc. I will try and comment the latest imports, but I didn't add any imports today that I can think of I will give a shot though. Thanks again!